# SQL Server service is crashed when using distributed transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, distributed-transactions, dblink, oraoledb

Recently I've configured the dblink using OraOLEDB provider, the DBLINK was working, however when I'm trying to use distributed transaction on the DBLINK, my SQL Server service is crashed and when I traced the event viewer log, it produced me below information:

```
Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 2017.140.2027.2, time stamp: 0x5d04c374
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.18362.815, time stamp: 0xb29ecf52
Exception code: 0xc0000374
Fault offset: 0x00000000000f9229
Faulting process ID: 0x2504
Faulting application start time: 0x01d65806f5dbe7a2
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS02\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report ID: 5ebfb503-7d08-4ce5-8fc5-a002f3171d65
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? Mind to share with me? thanks.

Comment: Does the Windows Server have Distributed Transactions installed via Roles in Server Manager?

Comment: Hi, i'm using windows 10, but yes i've Distributed Transactions installed, below are the services that i enable:
- OracleMTSRecoverService
- Distributed Transaction Coordinator

also, the configuration i've on the sql linked server is:
- allow in process
- Enable promotion of Distributed Transaction

Had configure on dcomcnfg as :
- enable Network DTC Access
- Allow inbound & outbound

hence i can't find anything wrong with my configurations

Comment: And you're connecting to a local Oracle database server, not Oracle Database Exadata Express Cloud Service? (OraOLEDB doesn't support the later with Distributed Transactions.)

Comment: Hi, oh is it ?  because i'm still using Oracle 11g, and actually i tried successfully before, but dont know what happened that suddenly caused this issue